# How to store the value of the listbox value?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

the page is post backing every time when i click the button(btnadd).could any one tell me how to store the selected  value of the listbox.Here am adding from one listbox to another listbox.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ListBoxExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="ListBoxExample"
    EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Adding,removing elements from First Listbox to Second Listbox</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .lstbx1
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: medium;
            font-style: normal;
            background-color: Aqua;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
        .lstbx2
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: medium;
            font-style: normal;
            background-color: Lime;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnadd').click(function () {
               // var originalList = $("#<%= this.lstbx1.ClientID %>");
                var items = $('option', originalList);
                var targetList = $("#<%= this.lstbx2.ClientID %>");
                $("#lstbx1 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#lstbx2");
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstbx1" runat="server" CssClass="lstbx1" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <asp:ListItem>John</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Peter</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Sam</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstbx2" runat="server" CssClass="lstbx2"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnadd" value="Add" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnremove" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store where? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: @enjoyprogramming: Your code should work perfectly if you remove the comment for originalList line. What's the problem?

Comment: After removing that commented line its not working.

Comment: I just tried to creating a web application and this page. it works fine. Which browser are you using and does this page contain anything else or only this code?

Comment: After uncommenting works perfect in IE and firefox, you added anything else ?

Comment: You have made it multiple select that part doesn't work but single selected sure does and there is no postback !

Answer (score 0):

Save the changes you make in jquery click to a hiddenfield value f.e. a comma separated list of values which are changed, split the values at server side and add them in listbox. Otherwise your changes are not persisted after Postback.

[Items not added to ListBox after using jQuery .appendTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764864/items-not-added-to-listbox-after-using-jquery-appendto)