# Moving items in listboxes and capturing in server side

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to move items between 2 listboxes using jQuery code

```
function move_list_items(sourceid, destinationid) {
    $("#" + sourceid + "  option:selected").appendTo("#" + destinationid);
}

//this will move all selected items from source list to destination list
function move_list_items_all(sourceid, destinationid) {
    $("#" + sourceid + " option").appendTo("#" + destinationid);
}
```

and my listbox code is like this

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFirst" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p align="center">
                <input id="btnRight" type="button" value=">" onclick="move_list_items('lstFirst','lstSecond');" />
            </p>
            <p align="center">
                <input id="btnLeft" type="button" value="<" onclick="move_list_items('lstSecond','lstFirst');" />
            </p>
            <p align="center">
                <input id="btnRightAll" type="button" value=">>" onclick="move_list_items_all('lstFirst','lstSecond');" />
            </p>
            <p align="center">
                <input id="btnLeftAll" type="button" value="<<" onclick="move_list_items_all('lstSecond,'lstFirst');" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSecond" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

The items move fine, but I cannot access the moved items from the lstSecond listbox using lstSecond.items. The count is zero. How can I access the added items from codebehind for saving?

Comment: Can you post some of the asp for this?  You may need a runat="server" tag on the element to make it available to the codebehind.

Comment: [Items not added to ListBox after using jQuery .appendTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764864/items-not-added-to-listbox-after-using-jquery-appendto/1764927#1764927)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your server side control (ListBox) doesn't read it's state from client side html, it always gets populated on server side (either from Markup or Code behind).

So one way to achieve your goal is to store items (of each listbox) in a client side hidden field as soon as you change them by jQuery. Then in server side you need to populate your listboxes based on the value presented in the hidden field (if any).

Comment: Thanks! ...makes perfect sense! I kind of expected that, butI had really liked jQuery code, but hidden field solution was not appealing to me. I am going with server side code, but with updatepanel to avoid postback experience.